# SQL column compare

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in the same table in SQL one for the number, a name, and another unrelated data. The numbers repeat for a certain amount of times and have a name next to them, there can't be a name twice on the same number, but the names can be present in multiple different numbers. I need to make an SQL query to find what names have been under the same number the most amount of times. Any help will be very appreciated.

Example: SQL query will find what names have been grouped together the most.

```
1 Bill 
1 Bob
1 Dave
2 Bob
2 John
2 Bill
```

Comment: what's your DBMS?

Comment: According to your problem statement:  " there can't be a name twice on the same number".  The maximum value of "I need to make an SQL query to find what names have been under the same number the most amount of times is 1.  Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm - you would like to find

- The pairs of names that occur together within a 'number'
- Of those, find the pair that occurs most often

The trick here is to get all the pairs, then count how many 'numbers' that pair appears in.

To get the pairs, join the table to itself (on the number) - and then to only have one pairing in each, also join on name with the first in the pair < second in the pair.

The answer to this question depends on your database (SQL Server, MySQL, etc). However, here is an example written in T-SQL but it is fairly generic that does most of the work: it shows the counts and orders them by the the relevant count.

- Feel free to get the TOP or LIMIT 1 just to get a pair with the most matches (noting that if there is a tie, only one would be chosen this way)
- Alternatively modify the query to work out what the maximum number is, then get the pairs with that number.

```
CREATE TABLE NameGrps (NameNum int, Name varchar(30));
INSERT INTO NameGrps (NameNum, Name)
VALUES
(1, 'Bill'), 
(1, 'Bob'), 
(1, 'Dave'), 
(2, 'Bob'), 
(2, 'John'), 
(2, 'Bill');

SELECT  NamePairs.FirstInPair, NamePairs.SecondInPair, COUNT(NameNum) AS Num_Paired
FROM
    (SELECT A.Name AS FirstInPair, B.Name AS SecondInPair, A.NameNum
    FROM NameGrps A
        INNER JOIN NameGrps B ON A.NameNum = B.NameNum AND A.Name < B.Name
    ) AS NamePairs
GROUP BY NamePairs.FirstInPair, NamePairs.SecondInPair
ORDER BY COUNT(NameNum) DESC, NamePairs.FirstInPair, NamePairs.SecondInPair;
```

And here are the results of the above

```
FirstInPair  SecondInPair  Num_Paired
Bill         Bob           2
Bill         Dave          1
Bill         John          1
Bob          Dave          1
Bob          John          1
```

If you take a TOP or LIMIT 1 of that, it will find the pair of Bill and Bob is the most frequent.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e6b7fd06a47234a831dac1160f30b01) with the query, as well as additional information (e.g., what the sub-query does, and adding a TOP 1 version).